# Как убрать прокрутку страницы сайта, когда листаешь слайдер пальцем?

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, slider, mobile-development, mobile-web

Вот к примеру как на гугле
[image: картинка с гугла]

Ты когда скролиш картинки и сайт при этом не ездит вверх-вниз, вот как можно такое реализовать на своем сайте, а то задолбало когда листаешь слайды, то ездит сайт вверх-вниз, зависимости от того под каким углом ты листаешь пальцем тот слайдер

Answer (score 0):

вот ответ на мой вопрос, как оказалось просто https://dle-faq.ru/faq/layoutquest/24508-pochemu-pri-vertikalnoy-prokrutke-na-slaydere-ne-prokruchivaetsya-stranica.html